# TinyMCE, insert HTML into specific TinyMCE instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have multiple TinyMCE editors on one page and I need to insert HTML in a specific one, currently when I insert HTML, it inserts it into the last one:

My init code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // enable tinyMCE on shortDescription
    tinymce.init({
        mode : "exact",
        elements :"shortDescriptionHtml",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        relative_urls : false,
        remove_script_host : false
    });

    // enable tinyMCE on fullDescription
    tinymce.init({
        mode : "exact",
        elements :"fullDescriptionHtml",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        relative_urls : false,
        remove_script_host : false
    });

    // enable tinyMCE on Terms And Conditions
    tinymce.init({
        mode : "exact",
        elements :"termsAndConditionsHtml",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        relative_urls : false,
        remove_script_host : false      
    });

});
</script>
```

Now when I try to do

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<img src="'+imgsrc+'" />');
```

It inserts the image in the last TinyMCE editor, which is the terms and conditions one, how do I insert that image into the first or second TinyMCE editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a certain instance of editor. I guess, something like that: `tinymce.get($(el).attr('id'));`?

check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/svCp2/. The line here is:

```
tinymce.get('c3').setContent('sdf');
```

Comment: This worked for me:
tinymce.get($("#fullDescriptionHtml").attr('id')).execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<img src="'+imgsrc+'" />');

Thanks for the quick answer!!

Comment: okey. But what is the reason to get elemenet by id for accessing to it's id? I means `$("#fullDescriptionHtml").attr('id')` = `#fullDescriptionHtml` :)

Comment: Yep, that works perfectly, haven't done javascript in 5 years, so a little rusty :-)
       tinymce.get("fullDescriptionHtml").execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<img src="'+imgsrc+'" />');

Comment: Cool! Nice approach :)

Answer (score 0):

```
tinymce.get("editorID").execCommand(
    'mceInsertContent',
    false,
    '<img src="'+imgsrc+'" />'
);
```

where "editorID" is your editor ID selector

```
<div id="editorID">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the activeEditor object:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<img src="'+imgsrc+'" />');
```